# Perl code to check the last line number of a file

Tags: perl, file-io

I have writeen a perl code that writes the number of lines it is one by one processing. I would like to get only the last line number of a file. The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
using strict;
using warnings;

my $qbsid_dir = "/root/deep/";
opendir (DIR, "$qbsid_dir") or die "Cannot open the directory!\n";
while (my $file = readdir DIR){
    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
    open(FH, "$qbsid_dir/$file") or die "Cannot open the file\n";
    while (my $line = <FH>){
            print "$.\n";
    }
    close (FH);
}
closedir (DIR);
```

The '/root/deep' directory contains two files. One with 90 lines and other with 100 lines written in the files.

I want those numbers to be printed instead of individual numbers such as 1..90 and 1..100 by $.

Thanks.

Comment: Move the `print` outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last line number, wait to print `$.` until outside the `while` loop for processing the file:

```
open my $fh, '<', "$qbsid_dir/$file" or die "Can't open $file: $!";

1 while (<$fh>);
print "$file -> $.\n";

close $fh;
```

Be sure to read: [perlfaq5 - How do I count the number of lines in a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file%3f)

Answer (score 4):

Do you really want to use Perl ?

```
wc -l <File>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It also print the last number of the filename.

```
$filedir = '/root/deep/';
opendir (dir, "$filedir");
@directory = readdir(dir);
@grep = grep{m/.*\.txt/g} @directory;  #It matches the particular file format
foreach $dir(@grep){
    open(file,"$filedir/$dir");
    @line =<file>;
    $total = @line;     #$total variable store the last file number from array (@line)
    print "File $dir Last line \t: $total\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use oneliner too

```
perl -nE '}{say $.' filename
#or
command | perl -nE '}{say $.'
```

test

```
$ seq 10 | perl -nE '}{say $.'
10
$ seq 10 | wc -l
      10
```